# Voltage Transformation Efficiency

Tags: voltage

Is the power loss during the stepping up / down of voltages, in transformers, comparable to that of raw current running through cross-country wires?

How much energy is saved?

Comment: Woah woah woah. A transformer doesn't cause power loss unless there's already loss in the wires.

Comment: Modern transformers are very, very efficient. I think like around 99% efficiency? Pretty sure that power losses from transmission lines are much greater than losses from transformers in modern electric power transmission systems.

Comment: post sam's response as an answer, not a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Modern transformers are very, very efficient. I think like around 99% efficiency? Pretty sure that power losses from transmission lines are much greater than losses from transformers in modern electric power transmission systems.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the ratio as well? How efficient is converting 5V to 24V or vice versa? I have heard that buck converting (decreased output voltage) is more efficient than boost converting (increased output voltage).